# 3D Column Sort (Leighton) Algorithm

Tags: sorting, matrices

Suppose you have a matrix A (9x3) of Real numbers and want to sort in columnwise. In this case we can use Leighton [ColumnSort](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~cs191/Stupid%20Columnsort%20Tricks.pdf) algorithms to achieve this.

But question is, how can I sort 3 dimensional (parallelepiped) of real number using the same modified algorithm?

Algorithm for 2D matrix and My idea for 3D parallelepiped: 
2D Column Sort:
1, 3, 5, 7 steps: Sort column (array of numbers) however you like
2, 4 steps: transpose columns to rows and reverse transpose
6, 8 steps: forewards shift and backwards shift

3D Column Sort:
1, 3, 5, 7 steps: Sort leftmost facet (matrix) by column sort
2, 4 steps: transpose facets from left side to facets to the front and reverse transpose
6, 8 steps: shift but **HOW**?
So, What will be the 6,8 steps for my approach? Or if that is not correct what is the algorithms for 3D Column Sort at all?

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a more specific link for column sort than to a google search? It was not very helpful to me in understanding your question.

Comment: http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~cs191/Stupid%20Columnsort%20Tricks.pdf